# Python: send file to a server without third-party libraries?

Tags: python, file, client, server

I have a Python client behind a NAT and a python server with a public IP address. My job is to send a **pcap file** (the size of a few MB) from the client to a server, as well as a **dictionary** with some data.

Is there any easy way of doing this without resorting to third-party libraries (e.g. twisted, tornado)?
If not, what's the easiest alternative?

I thought I could send the pcap file through **http** so that it would be easier to read it on the server side, and perhaps I could do the same with the dictionary by first **pickling** it. Would it be a good solution?

(I have complete control on the server, where I can install whatever)

Answer (score 1):

Is FTP a usable solution for you?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

http://effbot.org/librarybook/ftplib.htm

Comment: Hmm. This way the client and the server should at least agree on the destination path of the file, so that the server will know to which it belongs, right?

Comment: I don't know how your systems are configured but it's more usual that there is an FTP listener on a server than on a client, so you'll probably be sending the file from the client to the server. But you can write some logic on the clientside app to decide which remote directory to send to, or you can write a process on the server side to check for files deposited in the FTP directory and then copy them to wherever (based on filename, filetype, file content or whatever.)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I could let client and server first agree on the name of the file that the server will receive and the port number on which the ftp server will be listening for incoming files. Then, once the transfer is done, I kill the ftp server and the "real" server will load the contents of the transferred file. Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: If you did something like include timestamps in the names of the sent files, so that filenames were always guaranteed to be unique, then you don't need to kill the ftp process. Your other process can start consuming file1.timestamp1 while file2.timestamp2 is still being sent across. BTW if you prefer to use SFTP you could use Fabric (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html?highlight=sftp) although that is a third-party library so doesn't fit your brief (but apparently it's not difficult to use).

Answer (score 1):

If you can install software on the server, and the server allows HTTP connections, you can write your own simple HTTP server (Python has libraries for doing that).  If not, the answer would depend on what services are available on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use just the classic sockets with TCP!

You just need to send the file via TCP sockets and receive it in a TCP socket server.

Read it as a file, send it and receive it.

This might give you some tip about sockets: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Later I'll post a little script in case you didn't solve your doubt.

Comment: Yeah, but with TCP you have a stream, so you have to take care of file size, beginning and end of file. I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you in this way. But as you said you didn't want third-party libraries, I understood that socket would be a good choice.

Comment: Sure. My idea was to install as little as possible on the client side and install whatever makes my life easier on the server side. :)